# Problem with using an SFML texture in a vector probably due to my C++ incompetence

Tags: c++, pointers, game-development

I'm creating a C++ rpg using SFML library.
I've got a problem with using the textures I correctly assigned to a vector "mapTextures" in Map class.

Here's the code for loading and assigning:

```
void Map::AssignNewTexture(std::string name, sf::IntRect intRect)
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("Textures/Map/" + mapName + "/" + name, intRect);
    ExtendedTexture exTexture(sf::Texture(texture), name);
    ExtendedTexture* exTexturePtr;
    exTexturePtr = &exTexture;

    mapTextures.resize(mapTextures.capacity() + 1);
    mapTextures.assign(mapTextures.capacity(), exTexturePtr);
}
```

Note that the *mapTextures* vector is a pointer. (and I'm not that proficient in pointers as much as I would want to)

Seems like that part of code is fine, as when I debugged the whole thing, in the scope of the method below everything was fine, the textures were loaded etc.

```
void Map::BakeTextures()
{
    AssignNewTexture("grass.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("grasscity.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("forest.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("forestcity.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("desert.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("desertcity.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("arctic.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("player.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("mountains.png", sf::IntRect(0, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("mountains.png", sf::IntRect(16, 0, 16, 16));
    AssignNewTexture("mountains.png", sf::IntRect(32, 0, 16, 16));
        //... (i skipped some more - there's around 25 textures)
}
```

I have a proof, that textures are loading. so that's ok.
So if that was ok, what happens next? Well, an exception.
When I try to use the method below, there's an exception thrown at me, and I can see that for some reason, there's 12138 textures in the vector (!), and all of them have exactly the same absurd amount of x size, and y size of 144, and all have the same gibberish value for the name. What could have happened?

Here's where the exception is pointing me at, in the vector file.

```
_CONSTEXPR20_CONTAINER bool _Large_string_engaged() const noexcept {
#ifdef __cpp_lib_constexpr_string
        if (_STD is_constant_evaluated()) {
            return true;
        }
#endif // __cpp_lib_constexpr_string
        return _BUF_SIZE <= _Myres;
    }
```

Here's the definition for mapTextures:

```
std::vector<ExtendedTexture*> mapTextures;
```

And the ExtendedTexture class. As you can see, it's pretty rudimentary.

```
class ExtendedTexture
{
public:
    sf::Texture mainTexture;
    std::string name;
    ExtendedTexture(sf::Texture mainTexture, std::string name)
    {
        this->mainTexture = mainTexture;
        this->name = name;
    }
};
```

And here's the exception itself:
Unhandled exception at 0x004C307C in Hack n' Slash 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020.

Thank you for the help - in advance.

I tried to use different functions for the vector, but I'm quite bad at pointers, and I think they might be the reason I failed here.

EDIT: Solved it! Used std::move() to safely take the texture out of the method, while not losing any data. I had to change mapTextures into a normal variable, and it worked!

Comment: `exTexturePtr` is a pointer to local variable that immediately goes out of scope leaving vector filled with dangling pointers.

Comment: Makes sense, but my problem is I don't know how do it in another way. In C# I'd just use 'new', but here 'new' works a little bit differently.

Comment: Then you should learn how `new`  works in C++ and about RAII, about move semantic and about smart pointers as well.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. for example show us the actual definition of `mapTexture`.

Comment: As for your problem, you probably *don't* need a vector of pointers.

Comment: Also, instead of `resize` and `assign`, why not simply `mapTexture.emplace_back(exTexture)` (once you store objects instead of pointers)? On that note, a vectors capacity and a vectors size are two different things. Your current code would also try to use the vector out of bounds, even if capacity happens to be equal to its size.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I actually did use vector of variables before, but I just don't know how to get the loaded texture not get out of scope without pointers here

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually OP almost certainly needs a vector of pointers or some other means to prevent reference invalidation because `Texture` class lacks move constructor while other classes (such as `sf::Sprite`) keep references to texture objects.

Comment: Perhaps I should just create a vector of sprites then? I don't need to modify these textures, they are just simple 2D tiles for the map, would this be good here?

Edit: I also added the requested definitions for mapTextures & essential definition of ExtendedTexture (btw: idk about that name, seems a little bit not on point)

Comment: In order to create a vector of sprites you'll need to keep alive all the texture objects referenced by those sprites. And the only way to do this is to use dynamic memory allocation which involves figuring out pointers. If you want to keep things simple then perhaps you should just use array of textures with static size instead of vector.

Comment: Alright, so this just moves my problem instead of solving it. I'll try to read some more about them, but before I made this question I already tried to. I know what they are, just not exactly how to use them.

Comment: If you need pointers, then the C++ `new` operator worksthe way you need it to. *But* I would rather recommend you study some more C++ and learn about *smart pointers* like [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (for objects with shared ownership) or [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (for objects with only a single owner).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will learn about those.

Comment: Okay, I'm kind of surprised - std::move worked!